# Navicat Essentials Mac Database list

Tags: navicat

I have been using Navicat Essentials for some time and all worked well.

Today I opened Navicat and it gave me a message and asked me to download again from App Store. Which I did.

Now I am able to connect with the root user but it does not show me any databases. Everything is on localhost. If i connect from the terminal using the same root user - i can see all the databases. Mysql is running on localhost and terminal connection works well.

In Navicat the only thing that I am seeing is infomarmation_schema. No other databases are coming up.

It is not a privileges issue. I already checked that. The root user has all the privileges defined in Navicat.

Has someone seen anything like this before and can help with whats going on here.

Thanks,

Deepinder

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention. Even if i create a db from Navicat. I can see it in the terminal but not in the Navicat GUI. Its strange.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting an answer to my own question. I downloaded Mysql Workbench and when I tried to connect from there - it gave me an error.

Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist

I searched on this and got the solution -

mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force

Then restart mysql server and everything works. I can see the list of databases in Navicat now.

Thanks